# Staring ServerAgent into Jmeter Thread Group from Batch file (called from beanshell sampler)

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing

I've created a JMeter script that I should run later on Jenkins.

First in my script I add a Thread Group with 1 user, 1 loop and a Beanshell Sampler to start the ServerAgent to later get PerfMon metrics from the server.

In Beanshell Sampler I have added:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c D:/AppServer/AppServer.bat");
```

Inside the batch file (`AppServer.bat`) I have the following:

```
plink -v -ssh <username>@<host> -pw <password> -m D:\AppServer\commands.sh  > D:\AppServer\outputlog.txt
```

and in `commands.sh` file I have:

```
#!/bin/bash  
cd /ServerAgent-2.2.1  
./startAgent.sh --udp-port 0 --sysinfo --auto-shutdown
```

In the second Tread Group (multiple users and loop forever for 10 min) is the recorded test steps and in the third Tread Group (1 user, 1 loop) I have only PerfMon listener.

**Problem**

When I'm running the test seams like all Threads are starting at the same time and there is not enough time to connect to the server and so the PerfMon metrics will not display (`Connection refused: connect`).

**What I've tried**

I tried with timers, setUp Thread Group and setting delay on second and third thread groups but I wasn't able to find a solution. The bat file is working. I tested it with disabling the other tread groups and I'm getting connected successfully to the server.

Also tried a different approach. I split the first tread group into one .jmx test and the other two Thread Groups into other test. In Jenkins I'm having two Build Steps.
In the first Build step I have Execute Windows Batch Command:

```
jmeter -n -t D:/SearchOrder/AppServerStart.jmx
```

Then I've add another Build Step in Jenkins to Invoke Ant build file to start the test script with the PerfMon.
The Console Output:

```
...  
Executing test plan: D:\SearchOrder\AppServerStart.jmx ==> D:\SearchOrder\OrderSearch.jtl  
Created the tree successfully using D:\SearchOrder\AppServerStart.jmx  
Starting the test @ Wed Dec 03 04:52:25 PST 2014 (1417611145595)  
Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445  
Tidying up ...  @ Wed Dec 03 04:52:25 PST 2014 (1417611145847)  
... end of run  
Executing test plan: D:\SearchOrder\OrderSearch.jmx ==> D:\SearchOrder\OrderSearch.jtl  
Created the tree successfully using D:\SearchOrder\OrderSearch.jmx  
Starting the test @ Wed Dec 03 04:52:27 PST 2014 (1417611147067)  
Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445_  
...
```

The build are starting one after another and the server is not started in those 2 seconds, from one to another build steps.

Does anyone have similar experience or some advice on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can connect to the serveragent. 
Try

```
 telnet localhost <portNumber>
```

A successful connection can be checked by keying in test, the response should be Yep. Or by querying for metrics

```
metrics:cpu
```

should look something like

```
13.451776649746192  
11.688311688311689  
12.071156289707751  
16.64564943253468
```